# How do I filter requests objects by date range in Django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, python-requests

I've got a function for looping like this:

```
saved_date = request.GET.get('date')
start_date = request.GET.get('start_date')
end_date = request.GET.get('end_date')

if saved_date is not None:
   queryset = Contact.objects.filter(
       createdAt__istartswith=saved_date).values_list('phone', flat=True)
elif start_date and end_date is not None:
   queryset = Contact.objects.filter(
       createdAt__range=[start_date, end_date]).values_list('phone', flat=True)
```

So, I need to filter the objects by a date range, including the *end date*.
How do I filter all the objects that have a date between *start_date* and *end_date*?

Comment: Can you share the model and the HTML/Django form you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code if you are already taken **`createdAt`** as **`DateTimeField`** in **`Contact`** model

```
if saved_date is not None and (start_date is None and end_date is None) :
   queryset = Contact.objects.filter(
       createdAt__date__istartswith=saved_date).values_list('phone', flat=True)
elif saved_date is None and (start_date is not None and end_date is not None):
   queryset = Contact.objects.filter(
       createdAt__date__range=[start_date, end_date]).values_list('phone', flat=True)
```

Comment: How is that different from the `elif` part?